# The next level of spices (Indian cooking)?

Tags: spices, indian-cuisine

Normally Indian dishes are spiced up with chilli, turmeric, coriander and pepper and that seems enough for most cases. However when I go to the supermarket these days, there seem to be too many exotic spices packed into little bottles (jalapeno, basil, white pepper). I would like to know whether these spices go well with Indian cooking. What are some of these spices that I should consider putting in my shelf.?

Comment: Sorry, I dont think the two questions are same at all..

Comment: You are asking which spices are used in Indian cuisine @user2277550, that other answer gives you everything you need to know. If that answer does not fit your question then I suggest you re-phrase it, otherwise this will probably closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate - there are many spices used in indian cuisine that are regional or dish specific and wouldn't be found in the basic masala dabba, or the "duplicate" question - qasoori methi (northern cuisine), anardana (for grrrreaat chole), saffron, sichuan pepper(!) (found in some versions of goan recipes - and it does improve them!), curry leaves (southern, best used fresh or frozen) ... ajwain (for fried stuff), heeng (could be argued as being basic), kala namak, shahi jeera....